# c# - Access elements created by jquery in c# method

Tags: c#, jquery, dynamic, html-lists

In a user control I have an unordered list that contains items showing editable file data.

I create these items in my javascript using a JSON string set in a hidden field when the page is loaded or when the controlling element (`AJAX async file upload`) performs it's `OnClient_UploadComplete` function.

Everything I have is solid so far: the items are created on the client side, and I can get any values changed using an existing hidden field and transfer the data back to a BL object when I need it.

My problem is that during the server-side `On_UploadComplete` function, my server code cannot find any of the dinamically created items created by my javascript to add essential data to the new item.

I have to be missing something. The value I get from the control is `"/r/n"`..

My best guess is that my c# code is set up wrong. On the page, to find the ul I have:

```
Control m_ulFileItems = m_fuPhotoUpload.FindControl("m_ulFileItems");
```

I'll do some more loking, but this is an important aspect of getting this control to work.

Comment: adding runat=server to them when creating in my javascript won't make them accessible to my code behind as far as I know. I'll test it though

Comment: You're correct, `runat="server"` is a server side attribute that allows your code to access and manipulate the control before it gets sent to the browser. Adding that client-side won't do a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have any idea how you could be able to access these controls on server side. However, what I would suggest is that you pass their values from client to server, perhaps like this:
$.ajax({
 url: ...,
 type: ...,
 data: ids and values from your controls in json format
});

Here are some more details:
if this is the HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="placeHolder"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit();" />
</div>
```

And I have added some text boxes the following way:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        for (var idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++) {
            $('<input class="myInput" type="text" />').appendTo($('#placeHolder'));
        }
    });
```

Then this should work:

```
    function submit() {
        var jsonInput = '{';
        var inputList = $(".myInput");

        for (var idx = 0; idx < inputList.length; idx++) {
            jsonInput = jsonInput + 'txt_' + idx + ': ' + $(inputList[idx]).val() + ',';
        }

        jsonInput = jsonInput.substring(0, jsonInput.length - 1);
        jsonInput = jsonInput + '}';
        alert(jsonInput);

        $.ajax({
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/HandleSubmitClick",
            data: jsonInput

        });
    }
```

Hope it helps.

If you do not like the Ajax call to the server I can suggest to use a hidden control, and put that string into the hidden control before you go to the server. Then you will be able to take the value of that hidden control on the server side.

Anyway, this is the basic idea - collect and prepare the data on the client side, then send it to the server side somehow.

Comment: I've been looking for an hour, and it seems like this is nearly impossible.. I'll look at this and other routes, I need this functionality.

Comment: If you happen to stumble on anything, just edit your answer with a bit more detail. Hopefully it will lead to resolution so I can mark an answer

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden field to the page and before posting back to the server, scan all the items in the list, maybe create a JSON object which contains all the needed info from the created items, and set the hidden field value to this JSON. Now you should be able to grab that value and parse the JSON in C# and handle it from there.

Comment: That is essentially what I am doing during the data processing for the load and save functions. I've been using this method just to pass the data from client to server and back between objects, but indexing for the server side code and setter functions will have to be added in my javascript.

Comment: I had hoped that there would be a way to easily access the data strings I have set in the dynamic elements, but I'm coming to the conclusion that this isn't supported yet. Thank you for the input, and this may end up being my marked answer